# Creating new a Thread() is asking ParameterizedThreadStart object as a parameter in C sharp

Tags: c#

ah i'm very noob in Thread Programming and just started a basic step to create multiple threads, so i googled and got some snippets about creating Thread in c#, here is the snippet i found:

```
public MyThread(string name) { 
    count = 0; 
    thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run)); // here m getting error
    thrd.Name = name; 
    thrd.Start(); 
  } 

  // Entry point of thread. 
  void run() { 
    Console.WriteLine(thrd.Name + " starting."); 

    do { 
      Thread.Sleep(500); 
      Console.WriteLine("In " + thrd.Name + 
                        ", count is " + count); 
      count++; 
    } while(count < 10); 

    Console.WriteLine(thrd.Name + " terminating."); 
  } 
}
```

The error is **The best overloaded method match for System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart) has some invalid arguments**

Why the Thread constructor is asking me for ParameterizedThreadStart object, i want simple ThreadStart object to be passed.

Another Thing is ThreadStart class doesn't have a constructor with 1 argument i.e. it takes 0 arguments, but in snippet they have shown  `new ThreadStart(this.run)` this ?
m using C# 2008

Here is the complete code

```
using System; 
using System.Threading; 

class MyThread { 
  public int count; 
  public Thread thrd; 

  public MyThread(string name) { 
    count = 0; 
    thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run)); 
    thrd.Name = name; 
    thrd.Start(); 
  } 

  // Entry point of thread. 
  void run() { 
    Console.WriteLine(thrd.Name + " starting."); 

    do { 
      Thread.Sleep(500); 
      Console.WriteLine("In " + thrd.Name + 
                        ", count is " + count); 
      count++; 
    } while(count
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample that demonstrates the problem? The code you have posted works fine (once the obvious omissions are fixed).

Comment: @Mark: Your "complete" code is clearly incomplete. Give us an *absolutely complete* piece of code which can be copied and pasted into a new text file and just compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work, but you can try that:

```
thrd = new Thread(run);
```

The conversion from the `run` method group to a `ThreadStart` delegate is implicit.

I suspect you have a name conflict between `System.Threading.ThreadStart` and another type defined somewhere else in your code... Try to put the caret on `ThreadStart` and press F12 to go to the declaration

Answer (score 2):

That should be absolutely fine, because there *is* [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2.aspx) taking `ThreadStart` instead of `ParameterizedThreadStart`.

I suspect there's something else at play here... could you provide a short but *complete* example which demonstrates the problem?

Aside from missing the class declaration itself and variable declarations, your code compiles for me with no problem:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class MyThread {

    int count;
    Thread thrd;

    public MyThread(string name) { 
        count = 0; 
        thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run)); // here m getting error
        thrd.Name = name; 
        thrd.Start(); 
    } 

    // Entry point of thread. 
    void run() { 
        Console.WriteLine(thrd.Name + " starting."); 

        do { 
            Thread.Sleep(500); 
            Console.WriteLine("In " + thrd.Name + 
                              ", count is " + count); 
            count++; 
        } while(count < 10); 

        Console.WriteLine(thrd.Name + " terminating."); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: but why i'm getting error `thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run))` here as `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @FosterZ: I don't know, seeing as I'm not getting it with the complete code I've shown...

Answer (score 2):

I have completed the incomplete example you gave us and I do not encounter the same compiler error.

```
class Program
{
    static int count;
    static Thread thrd;


    public static void MyThread(string name) { 
        count = 0; 
        thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(run)); // here m getting error
        thrd.Name = name; 
        thrd.Start(); 
    } 

  // Entry point of thread. 
  static void  run() { 
    Console.WriteLine(thrd.Name + " starting.");

    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("In " + thrd.Name +
                          ", count is " + count);
        count++;
    } while (count == 5);
  }



  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  }
}
```